# Asp.net losing all information after PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-builder

I have a page and PopUp page "Example.aspx" :

In the first page I use The method of the `openModel("Example.aspx", "BtnExample")`.

and I have Textbox ' maybe more then 5 ' and in one of them i put a button that when the user click it will show that pop up form.
but the problem when the user full all other textbox after he click that button it show the pop up form but it empty the other textbox.

I don't know really how to solve it. I try in the button :

```
BtnClick.AutoPostBack = false.
```

and

```
btn.CausesValidation = false
```

but even that when it click in that button do the postback and empty all other failed.

so if any one know any other way to do it. i will be so thankful.

using just code behind. c#

Comment: Load data in control/page init (do not check the IsPostBack flag) instead of PreRende

Comment: You need to share the relevant code with the explanation of it. With whatever description you have written its not clear what you are asking and without seeing you code it is not possible to figure out what is wrong with your code and how to correct it.

Comment: Set Enable View State=true

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I can't share my code sorry for that. because is so biggggg and i can't put it. and for my question is clear i guess no need for code i guess so?

Comment: @SmartestVEGA I try with it but is not the solution. i didn't work

Comment: @SmartestVEGA and how to lead that data?

Answer (score 0):

if (IsPostBack)
{
    dropdown.SelectedValue = Request.Form[dropdown.UniqueID];
}

Answer (score 0):

Try it with UpdatePanel and you can avoid PostBack the whole page instead of the specific section, here is the example:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnl" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button
      ID="DomainSeachButton"
      runat="server"
      Text="search"
      OnClick="btnDomainSearch_Click"
      OnClientClick="onMySearch();"
      Width="69px"
      AutoPostBack="true"
    />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DomainSeachButton" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: For me i use just the code behind without any code asp.net all code or control or anything else is just with using code behind

Comment: Server side or Client side you mean?

Comment: The two of them

Comment: Can you share a sample code, not yours you can relate your code to something else and then share, maybe that could help the community to find out the answers.

Comment: for the code even a example i don't know how to share it, because my code a little bit is so big to have a idea of it or maybe to give same code like it.